# Login to server and save output in my home

Tags: bash, ssh

I want to connect to my server

```
ssh aa@server.com
```

then to its node

```
ssh compute@server.com
```

then

```
cat /var/log/test
```

I want to save this output in my home directory.

I tried to search in Google but I couldn't find something useful. How can I do this with a bash script?

Comment: what is a "node" and what is a "category" in your context? how many servers do you have? on which server does the text file live? where do you expect which output?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by running the command on the remote machine and redirecting its output to a file. For example:

```
ssh remote_host "ls" > /home/youruserhomefolder/file_on_local_host.txt
```